# Como abrir PDF no WebBrowser do Delphi?

Tags: delphi, pdf

No *WebBrowser* do **Delphi**, executo um arquivo *.html*, que é um leitor de PDF. Preciso que, quando for aberto o leitor, carregue um PDF armazenado numa variável string do Delphi.

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var arquivo : string;
begin
 arquivo := 'teste.pdf';
 WebBrowser1.Navigate('C:\zLocal2016\src_Teste\PDF_atual\pdf\web\viewer.html');
end;
```

Obs: estou usando a biblioteca pdf.js:
https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou `WebBrowser1.Navigate('PDFJS.getDocument('+QuotedStr(teste.pdf)+')'`

Comment: E por onde eu passo o caminho do arquivo .html? @Andrey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O PDF.js não vai abrir no protocolo `file:///`, isso devido a questões de segurança com `XmlHttpRequest` (ajax), a única maneira que vejo de fazer isto funcionar é criar um protocolo próprio (se é que é possível) no Delphi, ou então criar um mini servidor HTTP que somente para o uso do PDF.js

Um exmeplo simples de servidor HTTP seria isto:

```
procedure TMainForm.HTTPServerCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
  AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'text/html';
  AResponseInfo.CharSet := 'utf-8';
  AResponseInfo.ContentStream := TMemoryStream.Create;

  TMemoryStream(AResponseInfo.ContentStream).LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'pdf.html');
end;
```

O comando contem o html do pdf.js:

```
ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'pdf.html'
```